# passing props from a page to another page in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

i have a dummy project.in my project i have two pages.(test1 & test2) i want passing a prop from page1 to page2.i know that i can use useRouter hook but i don't want set this prop as a query string.
in my test1 page i have a color variable.this is const and have a yellow value.i want use this color in my page2 as a prop(props.color)
this is my test1 page

```js
import React from 'react';
const Test1 = props => {
   const color='yellow';
    return (
        <div>
            test1
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test1;
```

and this is my test2 page

```js
import React from 'react';

const Test2 = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            Your color is {props.color}
        </div>
    );
};


export default Test2;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there are too may ways but for me, I think you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Example:

```js
//in your test1 
//foo is the key, bar is the value
localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")

//in your test 2 you can get the bar by using foo key
const bar = localStorage.getItem("foo")

console.log(bar)// bar
```

And here is a hook called [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) You can use for that or customize your own.

Comment: Second line should be `const bar = localStorage.getItem("foo");`

Answer (score 4):

Props are passed from a parent component to its child components. What you are asking is to pass props between sibling components (ie. page) which I don't think has a straightforward way to do so. Maybe you can try using React's Context API  so that your Test2 is not using any hard-coded value.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get data in second page by using `getInitialProps` after passing the params in Test1 page

**Passing Params**

```
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href={{ pathname: '/test2', query: { color: 'yellow' } }}><a>test2</a></Link>
```

**Getting Params**

```
const Test2 = ({color}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Your color is {color}
        </div>
    );
};

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const {color} = query

  return {color}
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: `getInitialProps` receives a single argument called context. This object has a property called `query`  which is a query string section of URL parsed as an object. Using `query` in next/Link just adds a query string to the URL.