# Dynamic routing in nextjs. How to implement fetch data in another react component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

i am building a book store and i have a list of books. Here is a code:

```
export  function Card() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [books, setBooks] = useState(null)
    const [selectedBook, setSelectedBook] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/books");
            const data = await response.json()
            const books = data.books
            setBooks(books);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            setBooks([]); // or [] or any other default value
        }
    }

    fetchData();
}, []);

if (!books) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

// if (!Array.isArray(books)) {
//  console.error("Data is not an array:", books);
//  return <div>Error: Invalid data format</div>;
// }
function handleBookClick(book, id) {
  setSelectedBook(book);
  router.push({
    pathname: `/api/book/${id}`,
  });

}
return (
    <div className="card__container">
        {books.length > 0 ? (
            books.map((book) => (
                <div key={book._id} onClick={() => handleBookClick(book, book._id)} className="card">
                    <div className="card__image">
                        <img src={book.image} alt={book.title} width={"130px"} height={"150px"} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="card__info">
                        <div className="name">
                            <span>{book.title}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="author">
                            <span>{book.author}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="price">
                            <span>{book.price}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="button__busket">
                        <button type="button" className="button__addtobusket">
                            Add to basket
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))
        ) : (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        )}

        {selectedBook && <BookDetails book={selectedBook} />}
    </div>
);
}`
```

And when i click on certain card of book it redirect to [id].js file in pages folder and i get a json data of certain book. Here is a code in [id].js file:

```
import Book from "../model/Book";
import {StatusCodes} from 'http-status-codes';


export default async function getSingleBook(req, res) {
  const {
    query: { id },
    method,
  } = req;

  

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const book = await Book.findById(id);

        if (!book) {
          return res.status(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND).json({ message: "Book not found" });
        }

        res.status(200).json({ book });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ message: error.message });
      }
      break;

    default:
      res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET"]);
      res.status(405).json({ message: `Method ${method} not allowed` });
      break;
  }
}
```

The problem is how to navigate to another component where i can render data of book?
`

I have tried to use getStaticProps in another component, but stuck how to implement that. Please give me a right direction to do that. Tremendous thanks in advance!

Comment: For your requirements try passing props as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445064/passing-props-from-a-page-to-another-page-in-nextjs

Comment: More advanced/production ready sollution is to use state management lile redux or use useContext()